# Why spontaneous nuclear fission not classified as a kind of radioactive decay?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radioactivity

In radioactive decays, one considers the alpha, beta, gamma and electronic capture scenarios.
Why is the spontaneous nuclear fission not considered as a kind of radioactive decay ?

Comment: I don’t know what source you’re relying on, but *I* consider it a decay. That said, heavy fission fragment range out so quickly that they don’t show up in most detectors so they weren’t assigned a Greek-letter designation.

Comment: @dmckee Thank you. This makes sense. I Don't get what you mean by "quick". Do you mean the speed of the flight of the fission fragments ? Why woul it be more difficult to detect fragment that go fast in a detector ? I believe that this is what particle physics detector do very easily ?

Comment: "range" means how far they travel in a medium of the first detectors at the time they discovered the radiation.  The α β γ  designations came with primitive detectors, not the sophisticated of particle physics.. (The more charge the fragment has the faster it is stopped in a medium )https://www.orau.org/ptp/articlesstories/names.htm

Comment: thank you @anna v

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least in the field of radiation protection, spontaneous fission actually is considered as a decay mode. For example in [ICRP, 2008. Nuclear Decay Data for Dosimetric Calculations. ICRP Publication 107. *Ann. ICRP* 38 (3).](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/ANIB_38_3):

> Spontaneous fission
>
> Spontaneous fission is a decay mechanism resulting in splitting of the nucleus into lighter nuclei, referred to as ‘fission fragments’, with the emission of neutrons.

In the ICRP-07 collection, 28 radionuclies decay by spontaneous fission.

> The decay modes are abbreviated as: A – alpha, B− – beta minus, B+ – beta plus, EC – electron capture, IT – isomeric transition, SF-spontaneous fission. The contribution of fission fragments and neutrons associated with spontaneous fission are included in the total energy.

Note that spontaneous fission has a half-life and a branching fraction like any other radioactive decay. For example, Cf-252 has a half life of 2.645 years and branching fractions of 96.908 % for alpha decay and 3.092 % for spontaneous fission decay. Excluding the contribution of spontaneous fission decay and only looking at the alpha decay would result in a wrong total half-life for Cf-252.